# IntelliJ error: "Empty response from server" - Run/Debug Configuration for a remote GlassFish

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish, web-deployment, remote-server, glassfish-5

I am trying to associate my remote glassfish 5.1 server with my IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1
but I am getting the error:

```
Error running 'GlassFish 51': Unable to connect to the example.com:4848, reason: com.intellij.javaee.process.common.WrappedException: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Empty response from server.
```

The remote server is being running and it is possible to open a Glassfish remote admin console at an address `example.com:4848` . These are my settings:
(The blured host name is a domain name of my remote server. Say `example.com`)

[image]

[image]

Username and Password on the first picture are the same that I successfully use when entering the Glassfish remote admin console.

How to enable the connection? I can add more screenshots of the configuration and add more information when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to turn on an option *Use SSL connection*. Strange but helped. I did not do anything about SSL at that web server. The urls are of an http type, not https...

[image]